# Retrieve cri-o information using golang

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, exec, cri-o

I am trying to retrieve cri-o information like containerID, pid using golang. The below mentioned code works in my mac but when I containerize it and deploy it on openshift 3.11 stack, it doesn't work.

`cmdStr` in the below mentioned code can be any docker or cri-o command e.g. `docker ps` or `crictl ps --no-trunc -a --quiet`

The go version used is `go1.14.1 darwin/amd64`

```
package main

import "os/exec"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    cmdStr := "docker ps"
    fmt.Printf("cmdStr is %s", cmdStr)
    out, _ := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", cmdStr).Output()
    fmt.Printf("output is %s", out)
}
```

The output from the above code which I get on my mac is

```
cmdStr is docker ps
output is CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

The same on openshift 3.11 in logs of the pod is:

```
cmdStr is docker ps
output is
```

The other option is to use code in this link : https://godoc.org/github.com/google/cadvisor/container/crio#pkg-subdirectories but I am not sure how to make use of it, an example will help.

`go get github.com/google/cadvisor/container/crio`

```
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/cgroups/v1_utils.go:86:31: undefined: unix.CGROUP_SUPER_MAGIC
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/cgroups/v1_utils.go:95:5: undefined: IsCgroup2UnifiedMode
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/cgroups/v1_utils.go:109:5: undefined: IsCgroup2UnifiedMode
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/cgroups/v1_utils.go:151:5: undefined: IsCgroup2UnifiedMode
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/cgroups/v1_utils.go:155:18: undefined: ParseCgroupFile
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/cgroups/v1_utils.go:163:9: undefined: Mount
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/cgroups/v1_utils.go:171:75: undefined: Mount
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/cgroups/v1_utils.go:172:16: undefined: Mount
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/cgroups/v1_utils.go:185:8: undefined: Mount
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/cgroups/v1_utils.go:209:37: undefined: Mount
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/cgroups/v1_utils.go:185:8: too many errors
# github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/utils
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/utils/utils_unix.go:19:17: undefined: unix.PROC_SUPER_MAGIC
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/utils/utils_unix.go:63:62: undefined: unix.SOCK_CLOEXEC
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? what errors you get?

Comment: I have updated the question with the output from the code.